# Line-height for all but the first line

Tags: html, css

Below, how can I add vertical whitespace where it says "*increase spacing*". `line-height` would affect the entire `right` box, but I want addidional whitespace only when a line inside `right` runs over and breaks.

[image]

See http://jsfiddle.net/dhT8E/

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="left">Left Text 1</div>
      <div class="right">Right Text 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="left">Left Text 2</div>
      <div class="right">
        <div class="horizontal">Stacked Box 1</div>
        <div class="horizontal">Stacked Box 2</div>
        <div class="horizontal">Stacked Box 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="left">Left Text 3</div>
      <div class="right">Right Text 2</div>
    </div>
</div>

.box {width:350px; height:150px; border:solid}
.item {padding-bottom:8px;}
.left {position:absolute;}
.right {padding-left:100px; padding-after:20px;}
.horizontal {display: inline-block; padding-right: 20px}
```

Comment: not understand what you say ?

Comment: are you saying like this : http://jsfiddle.net/dhT8E/2/

Comment: @DipaliVasani: Yes exactly. Is it possible to do that without manual adjustments to individual `div`s?

Comment: You can apply Dipali's suggestion to ALL DIVs in that box.  e.g. add "padding-bottom: 7px;" to .horizontal { }.
http://jsfiddle.net/dhT8E/2/

Comment: @ChrisWalsh: No, this will increase whitespace where the arrow in the image says "*don't change spacing here*"

Comment: Will each DIV always have text in it?  You could drop the 
.item {padding-bottom:8px;} (or set it to 1px)
and ensure that ALL text has that 7px padding bottom.
If a box has no content you can always set a min-height to it.

Comment: increase the .box height and check .

Comment: @user1153551: You are right.  This is harder than it first looks.
Do you know in advance which .right and .left cells are going to have .horizontal elements in them?
If you do, then this is a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/dhT8E/

Comment: @ChrisWalsh: That might be a way to go! Small problem is if text in `left` is longer than text in `right` (this can be fixed the same way I guess). Also, it's a bit less intuitive. Still, best fix yet. No it's not always text, might be form elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line-height` is what you need.

```
.box {
   line-height: 26px; /* adjust to your needs */
}
```

True,

> line-height would affect the entire right box

... but to fix that up - just remove / change the bottom padding on your items.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/dhT8E/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for some sort of conditional line-height? When a box contains more than two lines the line-height of those lines should be increased, but all single-line texts should remain unchanged?

I think you should approach the problem from another angle. A possible solution is to increase the default line height, affecting all text, and then correcting the single lines with a negative margin or reduced padding.

For example, if you want a line-height of 20px for single lines, and a line-height of 30px for multiple lines, set the line-height on 30px and a negative margin (or reduced padding) of 10px on the box itself.

```
<p>Single line</p>
<p>Multiple lines with<br />increased spacing</p>
<p>Single line</p>
<p>Single line</p>

p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: -5px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Working example @ http://jsfiddle.net/xw3af/

Answer (score 1):

My proposed answer is to apply padding-bottom on .left, .right and .horizontal but UNDO the padding-bottom on those .right and .left that contain a .horizontal.  I use .nodrop to do this.  Empty .left and .right can be managed with a min-height.

http://jsfiddle.net/dhT8E/
HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="left">Left Text 1</div>
      <div class="right">Right Text 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="left">Left Text 2</div>
      <div class="right nodrop">
        <div class="horizontal">Stacked Box 1</div>
        <div class="horizontal">Stacked Box 2</div>
        <div class="horizontal">Stacked Box 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="left">Left Text 3</div>
      <div class="right">Right Text 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {width:350px; height:150px; border:solid}
.left {position:absolute;}
.right{padding-left:100px; padding-after:20px;}
.left, .right { padding-bottom: 8px; }

.horizontal{display: inline-block; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 8px; }
.item .nodrop { padding-bottom: 2px; }
```